# Extra Notification from my Windows Phone

Tags: notifications

On my Windows 10 desktop, I have notifications set to on from my Windows Phone via Cortana so that I can get battery low and related notifications when I have it near my computer.

I also have notifications set to on for Facebook and Twitter. But when my Windows Phone is near my computer, I get two notifications for Facebook and Twitter.

[image]

On my phone, I do want to leave the notifications for Facebook and Twitter on, so that they are available for me when I'm using my phone.

How can I change settings on my desktop so that I only get one notification from Facebook and Twitter whether my Windows Phone is near my computer or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by accident.  When you hover your mouse over the notification from the mobile device, a settings gear box pops up on the right.

Clicking on the gearbox will give you an option to not show notifications for this mobile app. That fixed my problem.

I don't need to, but I don't see a way to turn it back on if I wanted to, because if you go to the notification settings, you are not shown the apps so you cannot turn them on or off individually from there.

[image]